# Can i invoke another method inside of an argument list of another method?

Tags: java

I get an error related to the replace method. Can i invoke another method inside of an argument list of another method?

````
        String str="Candy";
        String newStr = "";
        for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
            newStr = str.replace(str.charAt(i),"");
        }```
````

Comment: What error You have ?

Comment: That's possible. The only invalid thing here is you are providing a `char` as first argument (`str.charAt(i)`) and a `String` as second argument (`""`) to `replace`. You could use `String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`str.charAt(i)` returns a `char`, and `String#replace` accepts a `String` as its first argument. Refactor it to

```
newStr = str.replace(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)),"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to "another method inside of an argument list of another method".

This call

```
 str.replace(str.charAt(i),"");
```

needs a method matching

```
 String replace(char, String);
```

No such method exists.  There are methods matching

```
 String replace(char, char);
 String replace(String, String);
```

(Minor liberties taken in the interest of simplicity; actual methods have arguments of CharSequence rather than String, but that does not affect the answer)